# Overstayed student visa in the UK 8 years ago

Tags: uk, germany, overstaying, pakistani-citizens

I am about to apply in Pakistan for a tourist visa for Germany, where I plan to stay for two weeks. Eight years ago, in 2009, I overstayed my UK student visa by 5 months.

Since then, I have a new passport which has no travel history, and my old passport has no mention of any overstay. However, one can easily check the expiry of my visa and stamp on arrival in Pakistan and conclude an overstay.

Will the UK overstay 8 years ago affect my current chance of a German visa?

Comment: just a note - the UK is still in the EU, but they have never been in the Schengen zone.

Comment: My edit, for clarity, removed the erroneous statement, the UK is not now 'out' of the EU.

Comment: Nobody knows whether it will affect it or not, depends on the consular officer.  If you're asked about overstay, you are advised to be honest. If they find out (and yes they can) you could be banned. The ban for overstay is 1-3 years so that period has expired and you're free to apply.

Comment: @SheikPaulofOsawatomie the ban applies to the UK, and the prospective application is to Germany, so the fact that any ban is no longer in force is irrelevant.  The applicant is free to apply in any case.

Comment: The big question here is whether or not you were detained inland and removed or served with an IS151a or IS151b at port or not. That's missing from your question and would make a lot of difference.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will affect your chance of a German visa.  But, as noted in [a comment](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92747/overstayed-student-visa-in-the-uk-8-years-ago#comment222560_92747), we cannot know what the effect will be, because there is no automatic refusal of a Schengen visa because of a past overstay in the UK.  Rather, the visa officer will look at your overstay along with everything else in deciding whether to grant the visa.

If you are asked about past overstays in other jurisdictions, do not fail to mention your history in the UK.  If you omit it, and the officer nonetheless finds out about it, you will almost certainly be refused for deception.

Comment: This. You will probably receive extra scrutiny but if you have stable income, family and perhaps even property then your ties are strong and you will have no problems. If you have none of these I wouldn't apply.

Comment: hmm, the only thing stable is my income, i hope that doesn't lose me two thirds of the advantage